# I've issue in setting up Django with Apache using mod_wsgi

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I've tried so much and feels i'm stuck and not getting anywhere Apache is giving an error which is

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wearpretty.settings'

I'm using 
python 3.6,
Django2.1,
apache2,
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Below are the files which are being used in this.

### wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "wearpretty.settings"
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

### virtualhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName lhwearpretty.com
    ServerAlias www.lhwearpretty.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/wearpretty

    <Directory /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/wearpretty>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess lhwearpretty.com python-home=/var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/venv python-path=/var/www/myprojects/wearpretty
    WSGIProcessGroup lhwearpretty.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/wearpretty/wsgi.py

    Alias /static/ /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/static/ 

    <Directory /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/static> 
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your **DocumentRoot** should be one folder up (minus 1 `/wearpretty`) and **python-path** var in **WSGIDaemonProcess** should be one down (plus 1 `/wearpretty`) : they must point to you Django Project root.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName lhwearpretty.com
    ServerAlias www.lhwearpretty.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty

    <Directory /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/wearpretty>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess lhwearpretty.com python-home=/var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/venv python-path=/var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty
    WSGIProcessGroup lhwearpretty.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/wearpretty/wsgi.py

    Alias /static /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/static/ 

    <Directory /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/static> 
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I would recommend to add this Directory node :

```
<Directory /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I tried This too almost every path i tried form /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/ to /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty/wearpretty

Comment: but luckily i got what's happening with my project.

Comment: Great. Go you !

Comment: you missed other occurrences such as the `Directory` directive where you tell where `wsgi.py` should look. it is hard to work with folders in depths with the same names. cheers

Answer (score 2):

As i started this myself i figured out there's some issue with naming of my directories.
Anyone who's starting first time he should be aware you can't use your Site dir name as your Project name.
so i changed it.

### Old Structure

```
Site Dir = /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty
Project Dir = /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearpretty
venv = /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/venv
```

### New Structure

```
Site Dir = /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty
Project Dir = /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/mysite
venv = /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/venv
```

### Virtualhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName lhwearpretty.com
    ServerAlias www.lhwearpretty.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/mysite


    WSGIDaemonProcess lhwearpretty.com python-home=/var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/wearprettyenv python-path=/var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup lhwearpretty.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py


    <Directory /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/mysite/static/ 

    <Directory /var/www/myprojects/wearpretty/mysite/static> 
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hopefully This'll help others as well.

Comment: actually, you were using the same name for many folder depths in so many places, you missed them. @DKH above tried and was close to a solution, but missed other occurrences such as the `Directory` directive where you tell where `wsgi.py` should look. changing the name just cleared the naming confussion. cheers ;)